# How to get out of this indetermination $\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \frac{\ln(2+x)}{x+1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Well, is just that, I can't remember a way to get out of this indetermination (with logarithm), can someone help me?

I'm studying for my calculus test and this question is taking me some time.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \frac{\ln(2+x)}{x+1}$$

Comment: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use l'Hôpital?

Comment: Is this a property of limits? I can indeed substitute the variable to get this form but I don't know why it is equal to $1$.

Comment: No, without l'Hôpital @egreg

Comment: Is there a way I can put this $\frac{1}{h}*ln(1+h)$ to be equal of one of the limits which goes to $e$? Like $1+h^\frac{1}{h}$

Comment: @LuanCristianThums, yes if $y=\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=\ln (1+h)^{\frac1h}\implies  e^y=(1+h)^{\frac1h}$

Comment: @LuanCristianThums you could've listed things you're and you're not allowed to use in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three methods:

$(1):$ Utilize $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$$  putting $h=1+x$ (as I have suggested in the comment)

$(2):$ Use Maclaurin [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) of $\ln(1+y)$ by putting $y=1+x$

$(3):$ Use [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) as $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\ln(2+x)}{x+1}$ is of the form $\frac00$

Comment: I'm not familiarized with the concept of Maclaurin series and I'm not allowed to use l'Hôpital's. I just can't see why $\frac{ln(1+h)}{h}$ is equal to $1$, can you please explain? Sorry.

Comment: @LuanCristianThums,  if $y=\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=\ln (1+h)^{\frac1h}\implies  e^y=(1+h)^{\frac1h}$ Now, $\lim_{h\to0}(1+h)^{\frac1h}=e$

Comment: Thank you, can I always say that $\frac{log(a)}{a}$ is equal to $\log(a)^\frac{1}{a}$?

Comment: No, $log(a^{1/a})$. In general $b*loga=loga^b$. I agree that making exponentiation bind stronger than function application is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @LuanCristianThums, ya $$\frac{\ln a}a=\frac1a\cdot \ln a=\ln (a^{\frac1a})\ne (\ln a)^{\frac1a}\text{ in general}$$ .

Answer (score 5):

$$
\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{\ln(2+x)}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)
$$
where $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:Take $w=(1+x)$ then you have the limit transformed as $\displaystyle\lim _{w\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+w)}{w}$

Solution :

$\displaystyle\ln(1+w)=w-\frac{w^2}{2}+\frac{w^3}{3}\dots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{w^n}{n}$ ,for sufficiently small ${w}$

So we have ,

$\displaystyle\frac{\ln(1+w)}{w}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{w^{n-1}}{n}$

$\displaystyle\Rightarrow \lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+w)}{w}=\lim_{w\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{w^{n-1}}{n}=1$

Comment: Surely we don't even needed to bother the whole of the Maclaurin series - is it not just enough to say that $\ln(1+w)=w + O(w^2)$ for sufficiently small w? I know that while its a minor point, it saves on a lot of writing/typing while getting the same point across, and stresses the importance that really only the first and second order approximations are needed, as after the second order term we know the powers of $w$ will go to zero anyways. This is more a stylistic comment if anything, but I feel it gives a slightly better intuition for what is happening.

Comment: You are right @AndrewD , but I always prefer writing any solution in the most elementary way(possible for me). So I have brought the Maclaurin series into consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer @AbhraAbirKundu, but my teacher haven't showed us anything about series yet, though I have studied a little of it by myself it is a bit confusing for me, don't think I would be able to use it in my test.

Comment: @LuanCristianThums you are welcome. You can then use the answer given by Stefan Hansen . It is also elementary.

Comment: Please @AbhraAbirKundu, can I say that $\frac{log(a)}{a}$ is equal to $\log(a)^\frac{1}{a}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is basically computing the derivative of the natural logarithm function, it's quite bizarre that using l'Hôpital's theorem is banned from the admitted tools.

If you're allowed to use substitutions, then you can change it into computing two limits.

1. Change $1+x$ into $1/t$ (for $x>-1$), so you can write

   $$\lim_{x\to -1^+}\frac{\ln(2+x)}{1+x}=
       \lim_{t\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t=\ln e=1$$
2. Change $1+x$ into $-1/t$ (for $x<-1$), so you can write

   $$\lim_{x\to -1^-}\frac{\ln(2+x)}{1+x}=
       \lim_{t\to\infty}\ln\biggl(\biggl(1+\frac{-1}{t}\biggr)^t\,\biggr)^{-1}=\ln (e^{-1})^{-1}=1$$

Since both limits exist and are equal, you have your claim. However this depends on what ”fundamental limits” you're allowed to use.